# Play iOS built-in sounds with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

Is is possible to play built-in sounds with `AVAudioPlayer`, to get around the limitations of `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`?

For example:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1360);
```

vs.

```
AVAudioPlayer

NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"???" withExtension:@"??"];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

[player play];
```

What would the path or code be (if possible)?

Comment: There is a repo in [Github](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) documenting the various system sounds and their paths. It may prove useful

Comment: @spassas How cool! I never knew this. You should give this as an answer (with, of course, the caveat that this is undocumented, unsupported, and subject to change without notice)...

Comment: @matt That's exactly why I didn't give it as an answer :) AFAIK the only "official" way to play system sounds is through the `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`. Everything else comes with a risk...